# finding href link using Selenium and java

Tags: java, html, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have some html code with href links.  Some of them are as follows:

```
<a href="#">
```

while others are like

```
<a href = "http://.....'>.
```

In other words for an xpath I can't use `//a[contains(@href,'#')]` nor `//a[contains(@href,'http')]` because they are mutually exclusive and each would work only for certain different href values.  There is not a universal string I can search for.

Now, theoretically, href should not be blank so if I could use something like `//a[href not blank]` that would be good.  Or even `//a[has href attribute]`.

Anyway to do that?

Comment: Tony, re-read your question. It seems like it is incomplete and could use some more information.

Comment: @SunSparc it's just that there were problems with HTML markup - fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check for `a` links to have the `href` attribute:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@href]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also check for specific instances of `a` tags using the XPath **or** operator:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@href='#' or starts-with(@href, 'http://')]")
```

This returns all anchor tags that have an `href` attribute equal to `#` or an `href` attribute that starts with `http://`.

This solution isn't as easy as the one from @alecxe, but it might give you more flexibility with your selections moving forwards. It also gives you the option to 'filter out' unwanted anchor tags. For example, this solution wouldn't return anchor tags with an `href` attribute that is a relative path eg `href="path/to/another/webpage.html"`.

Comment: don't I need an 'or' in there somewhere?

Comment: Actually, yes, agreed. See my edit. Can do it with either `|` or `or`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple CSS Selector that looks for an `A` tag that has an `href` attribute.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[href]"));
```